# Simple Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have `DatabaseContext` class.

```
public interface IDatabaseContext : IDisposable
{
    SqlConnection Connection { get; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : IDatabaseContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private SqlConnection _connection;

    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null)
                _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

            if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                _connection.Open();

            return _connection;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

And I use it in PageService class using dependency injection, for example:

```
public class PageService
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseContext _databaseContext;

        public PageService(IDatabaseContext databaseContext)
        {
            _databaseContext = databaseContext;
        }

        public IEnumerable<CustomPage> GetAllPages()
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomPage> pages;
            using (var db = _databaseContext)
            {
                //using Dapper.Net to get list of pages.
                pages = db.Connection.GetList<CustomPage>();
            }
            return pages;
        }
    }
```

Do you see any improvement / issue of my `DatabaseContext` class?

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen `GetList()` method on `SqlConnection` so I'm assuming this is your own class?

If that were the case would it not be best to have IDataContext abstract the Connection details away and return an IConnection contract.

```
public interface IDatabaseContext : IDisposable
{
    IConnection Connection { get; }
}
```

Doing this you can ensure your calling classes are completely decoupled from the implementation details of a connection.  Otherwise any implementation of IDataContext would have been coupled to a SQLConnection and you lose the benefit of the initial abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, with `IConnection` it looks better!
`GetList()` is the method of DapperExtensions library.

Comment: @sDima.  Ah I didn't know that about Dapper.  Makes sense now.  In light of that makes even more sense to either make it an interface/abstract class so that it takes these dependencies i.e. Dapper out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

In your dispose method you should also dispose your SqlConnection :

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _connection.Dispose();
}
```

About correct IDispose implementation read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx